# Getting stdout only after stdin sent in Python subprocess.Popen.communicate

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to write some simple tests using the the `subprocess` module in Python. The program being tested is simply:

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Integer? "))
    print('Output is', x // 12)


main()
```

To test it I'm calling this function:

```
def test_output():
    ret = subprocess.Popen(args=['python3', FILENAME],
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = ret.communicate(b"216\n")
    print(f"Output: {output}")
```

However, the `output` is capturing both the prompt from the target program's `input` call as well as the stdout that follows:

```
Output: b'Integer? Output is 18\n'
```

How can I get *only* the `Output is 18\n'` portion? I don't care about the prompt from `input()`

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, have you considered not printing the prompt? If you don't want it, then why is it there in the first place?

Comment: If you want to control an interactive application, use `pexpect`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Perhaps because the script is already written to be used interactively.

Comment: This project is using `subprocess`

Comment: Note that it's not good form to print prompts to stdout at all -- stderr is more conventional. That's where `read -p` prints prompts, where regular shell prompts (`PS1` through `PS4`) are printed, etc. It would be appropriate to adjust your program similarly. (That Python's `input()` prompts to stdout is... unfortunate).

Comment: Anyhow -- we have industry-best-practices for a reason. Some of the reasoning behind some of those practices is ease-of-testing. If you're treating the program under test as immutable here, you're increasing the test suite's maintenance load. Unless you've got an _actual reason_ for implementation decisions that make testing harder, it's typically worth reevaluating them.

Answer (score -2):

## Worse Approach: Waiting For A Prompt

Here, we read one byte in blocking mode (to delay until the prompt is printed), and then consuming everything else that's ready and waiting to be read *in non-blocking mode*, before switching back to blocking mode.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from select import select
import fcntl
import subprocess
import threading
import os
import sys

def test_output(timeout=0.1):
    ret = subprocess.Popen(args=['python3', 'testsubject.py'],
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           bufsize=0)
    # you probably want to replace this with a function that _stores_ stderr
    stderr_reader = threading.Thread(target = ret.stderr.read)
    stderr_reader.start()
    # wait until the prompt has been at least partially written
    prompt_start = ret.stdout.read(1)
    # go into nonblocking mode
    orig_flags = fcntl.fcntl(ret.stdout, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(ret.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, orig_flags | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    # read further output until there's nothing left
    prompt_rest = ret.stdout.read()
    print(f"Skipping prompt: {prompt_start.decode('utf-8')}{prompt_rest.decode('utf-8')}", file=sys.stderr)
    # exit nonblocking mode
    fcntl.fcntl(ret.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, orig_flags)
    # write to stdin
    ret.stdin.write(b'216\n')
    ret.stdin.close()
    output = ret.stdout.read()
    print(f"Output: {output.decode('utf-8')}")

test_output()
```

## Better Approach: Fixing The Program Under Test

The component at fault here is the program being called as a subprocess, not the program calling the subprocess. There are two major ways to fix it:

1. Don't print the prompt when not being run interactively by a user.

   ```py
   def main():
       x = int(input("Integer? " if os.isatty(0) else None))
       print('Output is', x // 12)

   main()
   ```

   This works because `os.isatty(0)` is false when a program is run with `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`.
2. Print the prompt to stderr, not stdout, so it's segregated with "diagnostic logs" ("ready for input now" being an example of a diagnostic status), not with output.

   ```py
   def main():
       sys.stderr.write("Integer? ")
       x = int(input())
       print('Output is', x // 12)

   main()
   ```

Comment: Neither of these are options. The task at hand is for the testing program to be able to test the target program's output in response to input

Comment: @BBrooklyn, please explain why "being able to test the target program's output in response to input" makes neither of these things options.

Comment: You're proposing modifications to the program being tested. Assume that is not under our control. Is there anything unclear about the original post?

Comment: Okay, _that's_ clear, but the answer comes down to "you can't do that (automatically, without changes to the target or a bunch more code)". If the target program is putting its prompts in the same stream as its output, then if you want to segregate them you need to write code that recognizes the two (as with regular expressions or similar). If you want it to be _automatic_, then the target program needs to play along. The two approaches given here are the industry-standard practices for how a target program _should_ "play along", to segregate its output from its prompts.

Comment: @BBrooklyn, ...by contrast, if you want a sequence like "wait to see the text 'Integer?', then write the item followed by a carriage return and read what you get back", then the tool to use is pexpect, as Barmar previously advised you. Mind, that's a _lot_ more code, because instead of just providing "here's the input to provide, now dump the full set of output" you need to script the sequence of prompts and inputs to provide after each prompt is seen when going that route.

Comment: I appreciate the comments...also not an option. Please do let me know if anything about the post is unclear & I'll edit it

Comment: "also not an option" meaning pexpect is also not an option? Could you explain why?

Comment: (Part of the point of that "why?" is to try to find compromise positions -- f/e, having a timeout, eating all stdout up to that timeout, _then_ providing stdin and reading stdout to the end of the steram; that would work, but I'd feel icky about it -- your test suite would be prone to timing conditions causing bad results)

Comment: @BBrooklyn, ...the above approach (that I said I'd feel icky about) has been edited into this answer.